# Problems with Sdk android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, sdk

I can not see options in my android `Android Studio`. I set my SDK but still  shows the options and cannot debug my project.

[image]

thank!!

Comment: Studio has many options, what options are you looking for?

Comment: what options you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You must check your defined build types and dependencies. It usually happens when you import some sample project or so. Apply the build type so that it knows what build you will be using.